# How to make AWS Lambda function open URL address (in some browser) and stays on it 1min?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, aws-lambda

Is there a way to create a Lambda function to open an URL in a browser (firefox/chrome etc.) and stays on that page 1min?

If yes - how to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you could build a custom runtime that includes a headless browser. Is this what you want? If not, you'll need a better description, including the _real_ problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: One way would be to use papeeter in lambda to open webpages. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63489068/iterate-over-multiple-payloads-and-take-multiple-screenshots-with-puppeteer-aws/63543157#63543157) has some more info.

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to do this?

Comment: Because company asked me to make it. It is one part of UI testing so need to make it work..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lambda for the UI testing, have a look at AWS CloudWatch Synthetics. I feel it will be a better fit for this use case.

1. Documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries.html
2. Blog - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-use-cloudwatch-synthetics-to-monitor-sites-api-endpoints-web-workflows-and-more/

You can also screenshot the UI screen. The blog has more details.